# Присвоить результат выполнения метода переменной - какой способ лучше?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Имеется метод, который производит некоторые вычисления и возвращает результат в self.переменную. Какой способ больше всего для этого подходит и почему?

№1:

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = self.func()

    def func(self):
        ...
        return result
```

№2:

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self):
        self.func()

    def func(self):
        ...
        self.var = result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методы №1, №2 не являются эквивалентными.

В одних случаях `self.reset()` может быть полезен (который `self.var` сбрасывает) и тогда,  чтобы код не дублировать или чтобы позволить поведение конфигурировать в подклассах, следует `self.reset()` вызвать в `__init__`.

В других случаях `func()` вообще из класса можно убрать (прямо в модуле определить), если `func()` это чистая функция, которая не использует `self`. Этот случай проще и поэтому более предпочтительный, если он работает в вашем случае.

В общем случае, вне`__init__` следует избегать создания переменных экземпляра, но обновлять уже существующие, конечно, можно.

Answer (score 2):

Первый лучше, поскольку хорошим стилем считается любые переменные экземпляра класса явно создавать в `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

```
# можно вообще не использовать переменные экземпляра класса, унаследовавшись от стандартного типа
# сам экземпляр выступает как контейнер list - те ненужно self.var
# + всякие "магические мктоды" типа __call__ - вместо func
# это упрощает работу с классом, но усложняет понимание происходящего

class ClassName(list):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = args, kwargs
        self.append(result)
    def __le__(self, other):
        return len(self) < len(other)

cn = ClassName([1, 2])
cn(3, 4, a=5)
cn(b=6)
print(cn)  # [1, 2, ((3, 4), {'a': 5}), ((), {'b': 6})]
print(cn < ClassName([1, 2]))  # False
```